# Site is not responsive in mobile, but is responsive on resize

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using css media queries to make a web page (currently not published) responsive. However, in Chrome Inspector mobile device mode, the site is not response. However, if I physically resize the browser window, it is responsive.

The media query begins like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in the `<head>` of your page:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

The viewport meta tag simplifies something that's [pretty dicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), directing the browser to behave a certain way, instead of the browser trying to estimate what the right way to display a page is. Having CSS breakpoints, as you discovered, may not be enough--for some designs and browsers, it will be fine, but it's up to the browser.

`width=device-width` uses a custom value (`device-width`) that is what it sounds like--set the width of this viewport to how wide the device is. `initial-scale` means something like setting zoom to 100%. So, together: let the viewport be as wide as the device, and don't zoom in or out.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to developing. Can you tell me why this works? I've designed other things before without using this and things have worked without it. Though this is the first time I'm designing with Wordpress/php.

Comment: @auto Absolutely. Edited answer. Doesn't have to do with WP/PHP, but can vary for reasons given above.

Comment: @auto You’re very welcome. Don’t forget to mark the answer as accepted if it’s up to snuff.

Comment: I tried this and the site now shows up in mobile, but it's caused other issues. Now the nav doesn't stick at the top all the time and sometimes the nav or body is too wide for the page. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @auto not without seeing a lot more code. and most likely in a different question.